# When returning a list pattern from a Haskell function how much of the original list is referenced?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

This is a question regarding Haskell list pattern returns.

If I return a cons-based list pattern that matches one of the function inputs, does the function return a reference to the head of the original list, or does it return a new list with a new head that points to the tail of the original list?

My understanding is that if a function has an (x:xs) pattern in its inputs, the x will reference the head value, and xs will be a reference to the tail of the original list, so that if I return xs it will return a reference to the tail node, skipping the need to make a copy of the tail contents.

But, what happens if I return the whole pattern, or part of the pattern? Does the compiler recognize the input pattern and return a reference utilizing a node in the original list, or does it start a new list for the cons-based lead elements and just reuse the tail?

```
foobar (x:xs) = xs
```

vs

```
foobar (x:xs) = (x:xs)
```

vs

```
foobar (x:y:zs) = (y:zs)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the compiler is doing this optimisation (or whether it is allowed to do that), but you can force it to not build a new list but use the original reference by [using an *as-pattern*](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Haskell-the-language doesn't define any of this. It's an implementation detail. The language is sufficiently high-level that the difference between both possibilities can't directly be observed, except in that a different amount of memory is used.

Generally you should expect that a new list is created, and only the tail re-used. But it's certainly something that the compiler can often optimise to re-use the whole thing.

If you want to be sure the original reference is reused, use an at-pattern instead:

```
foobar l@(x:xs) = l
```

If you want to be sure a new list is created... well I don't know if there's a completely infallible way. But I also don't see why you would ever want this in the first place.

Comment: This is the right answer. If we wanted to be extremely pedantic, `foobar l@(x:xs) = l` could still be "pessimized" to `foobar l@(x:xs) = (x:xs)` by the compiler, and that will still be legal. In a sense, we have no guaranteed optimization in one direction (the compiler might allocate or reuse) and no guaranteed non-pessimization in the other (the compiler should reuse but might choose to allocate after all). Still, when speaking about performance (and not merely semantics), considering these hypothetical "hostile" implementations is not really useful in practice.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The @-pattern seems like it targets my concern about being able to reference the original list on the return, while still utilizing patterns for the function logic.